# How to inject an entire module dynamically in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-mock

Alright, so I'm trying to set-up $httpBackend to use as a mock server for local development against an API. I have two services in separate modules: search and searchMock:

- search returns a $resource object that exposes the API verbs when in staging or production environments, and works as expected
- searchMock exposes $httpBackend which, in turn, responds with mock JSON objects, and works as expected by itself

I have another service, APIInjector, that determines what the current environment is based on a config file that's included dynamically by Grunt when the app is built and injects either search or searchMock accordingly.

My problem is, as far as I can tell from searching high and low, $httpBackend needs to be set-up within a module's run method. The problem with this is I can't inject the run method within my APIInjector's conditional logic.

How can I expose $httpBackend if the dev environment condition is met, and my $resource service otherwise? Note that I didn't include the calling controller's or the searchService's code, but I can if needed for clarification.

**searchMock:**

```
var searchMockService = angular.module('searchMockService', []);

searchMockService.run([
  '$httpBackend', 
  function($httpBackend) {
    results = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Jane'}];
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/search').respond(results);
}]);
```

**APIInjector:**

```
var APIInjectorService = angular.module('APIInjectorService', [
  'searchService', 
  'searchMockService'
]);

APIInjectorService.factory('APIInjector', [
  '$injector',
  'ENV_CONF',
  function($injector, ENV_CONF) {
    var isDevelopment = ENV_CONF.IS_DEVELOPMENT;

    // Check to see if we're in dev and, if so, inject the local API services
    if (isDevelopment) {
      return {
        Search: // Not sure what to do here to expose searchMock's run method???
      };
    } else {
      return {
        Search: $injector.get('Search') // This returns $resource from the search service, as expected
    };
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Why don't you make a wrapper service that either returns `$resource` or `$httpBackend` depending on the environment?

Comment: @jraede That's basically what the APIInjector service is supposed to do. Edit: because I have to repeat this same pattern throughout the application, I was trying to abstract it out to something more reusable.

Comment: Can't you return `$injector.get('SearchMock').run`? It's just a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put a final point on this question, I ultimately pulled this out to my build script (Grunt) and abandoned the above approach completely. Instead, I'm passing in the environment I want to build for (development, staging, production, etc) as a flag to Grunt and then loading the appropriate API service during the build.

Hope that helps someone else trying to implement backendless development!

Answer (score 0):

As bad as it looks at first place, i'd use the `document.write` method,if you are not using requirejs(it shouldnt be a problem with requirejs).

- 1 - bootstrap your ENV_CONF variable in a script tag as first script in HEAD tag.
- 2 - load all the common scripts
- 3 - test the ENV_CONF.IS_DEVELOPMENT in another SCRIPT tag.
- 4 - if true `document.write('<script src="angular-mocks.js"></script><script src="main-dev-module.js"></script>')`
- 5 - if false `document.write('<script src="main-prod-module.js"></script>')`
- 6 - profit

That way you dont need to deal with ENV_CONF.IS_DEVELOPMENT  inside your modules.

html5 boilerplate uses this technique to either fetch jquery from a cdn or locally

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html

Edit: I'm sure there are cleaner ways to inject services dynamically in angularjs,but that's what i'd do.I'd like someone to propose a better alternative.